# PowerShell Windows Forms - ProgressBar not displayed correctly

Tags: powershell, winforms, progress-bar

I would like to create a graphical interface in PowerShell using Windows Forms. I am working on a progress bar, which I would like to solve using the ProgressBar.

My problem is that when I call the Run function, the GUI progress bar is not in sync with the $ProgressBar.Value value. When the first $ProgressBar.PerformStep() command runs, the $ProgressBar.Value value is already 1, but the GUI progress bar has not yet moved. When the second PerformStep() command runs, the $ProgressBar.Value value is 2, but the GUI still shows a value of 1. When the third PerformStep() runs, $ProgressBar.Value is 3, but the GUI is still at 2. After the last command runs (Start-Sleep 3), the GUI finally updates and catches up with the $ProgressBar.Value value (3).

(The function is just an example, in the real code a ForEach loop will be applied.)

This is the sample code:

```
function Run {
$ProgressBar.Maximum = 3
$ProgressBar.Step = 1

$ProgressBar.PerformStep()
Write-Host $ProgressBar.Value
Start-Sleep 3

$ProgressBar.PerformStep()
Write-Host $ProgressBar.Value
Start-Sleep 3

$ProgressBar.PerformStep()
Write-Host $ProgressBar.Value
Start-Sleep 3

}

$MainForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{
    Text            = "Form"
    ClientSize      = "400, 600"
}

$ProgressBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar -Property @{
    Location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(60, 65)
    Size                  = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180, 10)
}

$ButtonRun = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button -Property @{
    Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150, 530)
    Size      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 40)
    Text      = "Run"
}
$ButtonRun.Add_Click({Run})

$MainForm.Controls.AddRange(($ProgressBar, $ButtonRun))
$MainForm.ShowDialog()
```

I have tried using $ProgressBar.Refresh() or [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents() after $ProgressBar.PerformStep(), but these have not helped either. Why is this happening and how can I keep the two things in sync?

I modified the function based on Jimi's answer. It looks like it works. Is the code technically correct? Sorry, I am still very new to PowerShell and programming.

```
function Run {

$ProgressBar.Maximum = 3
$ProgressBar.Step = 1

for ($i = 1; $i -le 3; $i++) {
$ProgressBar.PerformStep()
[System.Threading.Tasks.Task]::Delay(3000).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
Write-Host $ProgressBar.Value
}
}
```

Comment: Hummm, just tested what you posted here on one of my pristine sandboxes, and I am not seeing what you are describing on the first run execution. Yet, of course, since you are not resetting your counter, hitting the run again will always return the number of the last past per your count maximum. So, it may be potentially a host issue on your system. Try your code on a different pristine system or pristine VM. On Win 8-11, enable the [Windows Sandbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-sandbox/windows-sandbox-overview) feature and you can test that way.

Comment: Can you move the Form or interact with other Controls while Start-Sleep is *waiting*?

Comment: I've tried it on several machines and the issue persists on all of them. During the Start-Sleep process, I am unable to move or interact with the form. I have created a gif to visually demonstrate the problem: https://im.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-1-6b4d7098d7.gif

Comment: new link: https://s9.gifyu.com/images/gifde9efc76c7ee9ce9.gif

Comment: Halting the script, you block the Thread. You may want to use a Timer, or a loop that uses a StopWatch or similar and calls `[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()`, or run that snippet as C# code and `await Task.Delay()` or, translated to PowerShell, using `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, e.g. `$null = [System.Threading.Tasks.Task]::Delay(3000).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`, used wisely, otherwise this also blocks the Thread

Comment: @Tom, again, I get what you mean, but again, not happening on my end using your exact code. But again, I am calling from the ISE, vs in the console as you are. In most cases, In the console, you should call the form libraries/Namespace(s) as needed at the top of your script/function, just to be sure. The ISE auto-loads those, but the console does not.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, again in pristine sandboxed VM environments default OS-only hosts.

```
function Run 
{

    Add-Type -AssemblyName  System.Drawing,
                            PresentationCore,
                            PresentationFramework,
                            System.Windows.Forms,
                            microsoft.VisualBasic
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()


    $ProgressBar.Maximum = 3
    $ProgressBar.Step = 1

    $ProgressBar.PerformStep()
    Write-Host $ProgressBar.Value
    Start-Sleep 3

    $ProgressBar.PerformStep()
    Write-Host $ProgressBar.Value
    Start-Sleep 3

    $ProgressBar.PerformStep()
    Write-Host $ProgressBar.Value
    Start-Sleep 3
}

$MainForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{
    Text            = "Form"
    ClientSize      = "400, 600"
}

$ProgressBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar -Property @{
    Location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(60, 65)
    Size                  = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180, 10)
}

$ButtonRun = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button -Property @{
    Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150, 530)
    Size      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 40)
    Text      = "Run"
}
$ButtonRun.Add_Click({Run})

$MainForm.Controls.AddRange(($ProgressBar, $ButtonRun))
$MainForm.ShowDialog()
```

You don't need all those libraries, but I put the options here for context.

> https://gifyu.com/image/Sq9gw

***Update***

Yet, if your code update works for you, then this is just FYI.

***Update***

As I took a look at this on what I call ***spoiled environments*** (Meaning a fully loaded user and or developer workstation, MSOffice, all latest uOS updates, Dev tools, etc.). On spoiled machines, then what you are seeing is reproducible, meaning on an MSOffice-only host, Developer tools-only host, and an MSOffice + Developer tools host.

Comment: I don't understand why it works correctly for you and not for me. I've already tried it on four different machines and the result is the same on all of them (called from ISE and from console). There were both occupied and completely fresh virtual machines among them. In my real code, I also loaded the libraries that you wrote. It only works properly for me if I run the `[System.Threading.Tasks.Task]::Delay(1).GetAwaiter().GetResult()` command after the `$ProgressBar.PerformStep()`.

Comment: @Tom, all I can say is, yep, very weird. Yet, you have a workaround. So, at this point, I'd use that vs sweating this any further. I do plan on working a bit more on my so-called spoiled systems, where I can repro what you are seeing, just out of my own curiosity at this point. Meaning, working my way up from pristine to a spoiled system, testing along the way.